# Not requiring Apple app review for external app testing

Tags: ios, testflight

I have two apps that are currently being tested by external testers, via TestFlight.

When I do a new build of one, it always goes through app review before the external testers can try the app. Reviews are currently taking from one to two days.

Another of my apps is always instantly available for external testers, without needing to be reviewed.

I was wondering why this is the case? And is there anything I can do to not require a review everytime I do an update for external testers -- as is the case with one of my apps?

Answer (score 1):

Beta App Review (which is a faster process than a normal app review) is always required for external testers.

The testers on your other app are probably registered as internal testers. There's no review requirement for pushing updates to internal testers.

Comment: No, I just double-checked. The other app's testers are external. And I can assure you that, at least for this app, I've not had to go through app review at all to get it to external testers via TestFlight. As soon as the app is uploaded and processed, I am able to make it available to both internal and external users at the same time.

Comment: Maybe it's just a quirk of the way this particular app ended up being setup in TestFlight.

Comment: There's no official way to bypass the review process for external testers. So either you have mistaken something, or Apple have a flaw in their system that is not available to others.

Comment: Thank you for the response, @jksoegaard. But something is weird with my TestFlight. Last night, another app which was always requiring me to go through app review for external TestFlight testers, all of a sudden it's no longer requiring it. This is the second app that I can now send builds to external testers immediately.